# Dojo grid grouping head like Excel

Tags: dojo, grid

I want to display the following grid header style like Excel. Is there some perfect solutions available? And I've found [some solutions](http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/Dojo-Grid-Header-Column-Grouping-td926925.html#a2451700), but the cells borders cannot display normally.
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Didn't work for you ?

Answer (score 0):

That's easy to do with Dgrid and it's CompoundColumns mixin.

See the docs here : https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/wiki/CompoundColumns

See the tests here : http://dojofoundation.org/packages/dgrid/js/dgrid/test/complex_column.html